# Clear the 'All' checkbox when some of the sub-checkboxes have been un-clicked?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox

I have a form that has several check-boxes, and an 'All' check-box that, of course, fills or empties the rest. The issue that I'm running into is that I need it to un-check the 'All' box once one of the sub-boxes has been unchecked. The logic of how to do this seems to be escaping me at the moment, so any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code from that portion of the project:

```
public partial class SrsSelectForm : Form
{

/// Property to return the full SRS names for checked items

public List<string> SelectedSrs
{
  get
  {
    return (from cb in checkBoxes
            where cb.Checked
            select cb.Tag.ToString()).ToList();
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Unique Srs full names for all setting nodes on the current device
/// </summary>
private HashSet<string> allSrs;

/// <summary>
/// Tracks the checkboxes generated for the available SRS
/// </summary>
private List<CheckBox> checkBoxes;

/// <summary>
/// Constructor
/// </summary>
public SrsSelectForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  allSrs = new HashSet<string>();
  checkBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();
}

/// <summary>
/// Event handler
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">this form</param>
/// <param name="e">Event args</param>
private void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // center on parent
  Utilities.SetFormLocation(this);
}

/// <summary>
/// Retrieves available SRS for the setting nodes and creates check boxes
/// for selection 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="device">currently loaded device</param>
/// <param name="folder">the user's selected output folder</param>
/// <param name="node">starting settings node</param>
public void Populate(IDevice device, string folder, TreeNode node)
{
  // find all Srs output file names
  GetSrsNames(device, folder, node);

  // generate controls for them
  CreateSrsControls();
}

/// <summary>
/// Generates checkboxes for available SRS
/// </summary>
private void CreateSrsControls()
{
  int xPos = 8;
  int yPos = 55;
  int height = 24;

  foreach (string srsPath in allSrs)
  {
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

    cb.AutoSize = true;
    cb.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);

    // friendly name
    cb.Text = Utilities.GetSrsGroupName(srsPath);

    // store full name for returning to caller
    cb.Tag = srsPath;

    cb.Checked = true;

    grpSrs.Controls.Add(cb);
    checkBoxes.Add(cb);

    yPos += height;
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Finds all Srs for the settings tree
/// </summary>
/// <param name="device">the currently loaded device</param>
/// <param name="folder">the selected export folder</param>
/// <param name="node">a tree node</param>
private void GetSrsNames(IDevice device, string folder, TreeNode node)
{
  if (node.Tag is DeviceDefinitionNodeValue)
  {
    var nodeValue = (DeviceDefinitionNodeValue)node.Tag;

    if (nodeValue.IsRelayGroup)
    {
      string fileName = string.Empty;
      if (Utilities.GetUsableSrsFileName(device, nodeValue, folder, ref fileName))
      {
        allSrs.Add(fileName);
      }
    }
  }

  // recurse
  foreach (TreeNode subNode in node.Nodes)
  {
    GetSrsNames(device, folder, subNode);
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Toggles the SRS checkboxes in response to the All c/b changing
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">checkbox control</param>
/// <param name="e">event args</param>
private void CheckedOptionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (sender == cbAll)
  {
    foreach (var cb in checkBoxes)
    {
      cb.Checked = cbAll.Checked;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should hook into CheckBox.CheckChanged for each checkbox. You actually already have this event handler declared but I don't see where you have any checkbox hook into it. But anyways- just have it check to see if the checkbox is the "all checkbox" and if not, perform the logic you want to the all checkbox. I assume this would be to uncheck the all checkbox, though you could include logic to see if they have all been checked as well, in which case you might want to actually check the "all checkbox".

Code:

```
private void CreateSrsControls()
{
  int xPos = 8;
  int yPos = 55;


 int height = 24;

  foreach (string srsPath in allSrs)
  {
      CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

      cb.AutoSize = true;
      cb.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);

      // friendly name
      cb.Text = Utilities.GetSrsGroupName(srsPath);

      // store full name for returning to caller
      cb.Tag = srsPath;

      cb.Checked = true;

      // NEW CODE
      cb.CheckedChanged += CheckedOptionChanged;

      grpSrs.Controls.Add(cb);
      checkBoxes.Add(cb);

      yPos += height;
    }
  }

private void CheckedOptionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (sender == cbAll)
  {
    foreach (var cb in checkBoxes)
    {
      cb.Checked = cbAll.Checked;
    }
  }
  else
  {
     // make sure setting this doesn't fire the event again
     cbAll.CheckedChanged -= CheckedOptionChanged;
     // this would uncheck it anytime the others are changed
     cbAll.Checked = CheckState.Unchecked;
     //now resubscribe
     cbAll.CheckedChanged += CheckedOptionChanged;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. So, this is definitely progress. However, a weird thing is happening now: When I check the 'All' box, it checks everything like it's supposed to, then when I click on one of the sub-boxes, the idea is that it supposed to just clear the box I clicked and the 'All' box, but instead, it clears everything, including the 'All' box. Any ideas why? Thanks again!

Comment: Probably because setting `cbAll.Checked` in the event re-fires it. In the else you can unsubscribe right before you set it, and then re-subscribe: `cbAll.CheckedChanged -= CheckedOptionChanged; cbAll.Checked = CheckState.Unchecked; cbAll.CheckedChanged += CheckedOptionChanged;`

Comment: np. I updated this answer; hopefully @bkribbs won't mind ;) Don't forget to select this as the answer.

Comment: Ah thanks for the correction and improvement Drew! I approved the edit. Raymond, glad you got it working.

Comment: @bkribbs thank you very much for your help. This was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

In your `CheckedOptionChanged`, just add the `else` code:

```
private void CheckedOptionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (sender == cbAll)
  {
    foreach (var cb in checkBoxes)
    {
      cb.Checked = cbAll.Checked;
    }
  }
  else if (!((Checkbox)sender).Checked)
  {
    cbAll.Checked = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've placed each required checkbox into your checkbox list.

```
if(!fromSubCheckBoxes)
foreach(CheckBox cb in checkBoxes)
    if(cbAll.Checked)
        cb.Checked = true;
    else
        cb.Checked = false;
```

**LINQ**

```
if(!fromSubCheckBoxes)
    checkboxes.ForEach(o => o.Checked = cbAll.Checked);
```

Setting the `cbAll` box once an item is checked.

On **sub checklist check changed**:

```
if (checkboxes.Any(o => !o.Checked) && cbAll.Checked){
    fromSubCheckBoxes = true;
    cbAll.Checked = false;
    fromSubCheckBoxes = false;
}
```

This will cause your cbAll checkbox CheckedChanged event to fire. So throw a boolean in your cbAll CheckedChanged event to be sure that it is not fired by the CheckBoxList or your sub check boxes.

Comment: This sets the individual checkboxes when the all checkbox is checked; the OP is looking to set the all checkbox based on the individual checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your post correctly, you essentially want to toggle the state of the All checkbox based on whether or not the other checkboxes are all checked.

If that is the case, consider modifying the following method as follows:

```
private void CheckedOptionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (sender == cbAll)
  {
    foreach (var cb in checkBoxes)
    {
      cb.Checked = cbAll.Checked;
    }
  }
  else
  {
     cbAll.Checked = !checkBoxes.Any(cb => cb.Checked);
  }
}
```

This assumes, of course, that all your checkboxes are using this as their check changed handler.

Comment: This will set the all checkbox to be checked only when none of the checkboxes are checked; I think you would want `= checkboxes.All(cb => cb.Checked)`.

Comment: @zmidanen: Per my reading of the question, the All checkbox should check the other checkboxes, or clear them. This is standard behavior. .All(cb => cb.Checked) would return true only if they were all checked, which would check the All button, giving it the opposite of the desired behavior.

Comment: @MikeHofer I think zimdanen meant `!checkboxes.All(cb => cb.Checked)`. He's right; that line in your answer would set `cbAll.Checked` to false only if there aren't *any* checked. You could also use `cbAll.Checked = checkBoxes.Any(cb => !cb.Checked);`